# KendoListView: Display data from dynamic datasource

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I want to display into a list view data from a dynamic datasource, which means columns are not fixed and cannot be determined until requested.

Example:

- It could return an object list with columns `{ Id, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName }` or
- It could return an object list with columns `{ Id, LastName }` only

This could happen depending on the setup made.

I have a setup to determine which column(s) should be return upon querying.
My setup is an array that will list all the included columns.

- `this.includedColumns = ko.observableArray(["Id", "LastName"]);`

Now in my html I have,

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div id="items"></div>
    <div id="pager" class="k-pager-wrap"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="itemTemplate">
    <div class="item" data-bind="drag: { value: $data }">

        // Here I want to display what should be displayed depending on the setup
        // If the return objects has columns { Id, FirstName, LastName }

        // and in my setup I have only { Id, LastName }
        // here I need to loop through the includedColumns list and display the columns here

       Example:

       <div data-bind="foreach: includedColumns">
          <span>#: {{theIncludedColumnHere}} #</span>
       </div>

    </div>
</script>
```

Initialization,

```
$("#items").kendoListView({
      dataSource: myDataSource,
      pageable: true,
      virtual: true,
      template: kendo.template($("#itemTemplate").html()),
      dataBound: function () {
      }
   });

 $("#pager").kendoPager({
     dataSource: myDataSource
 });
```

Hopefully there's a possible solution for this. Thank you.

Comment: any chance can you include a fiddle in your post with code .

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar task with a grid. Maybe it helps finding a solution for listview.
The grid contained all possible columns. Depending on the actual data (the grid knew what data to expect once the user pressed a button) certain columns were hidden or shown.

For a grid you can do this:

```
grid.hideColumn("ColumnNameOrIndex");
grid.showColumn("ColumnNameOrIndex");
```

For listviews this get's a little more complicated but if you can add an id/class to the columns (eg. the column name) upon binding. You should be able to use something like this.

```
$(".myColumnType").hide();
```

Hope it helps finding a solution!